# Issue with choosing columns when creating max/min columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, max, dataframe, min

I have the following code:

```
def minmaxdata():
    Totrigs,TotOrDV,TotOrH,TotGas,TotOil,TotBit,ABFl,ABOr,SKFl,SKOr,BCOr,MBFl,MBOr = dataforgraphs()
    tr = Totrigs
    tr['year'] = tr.index.year
    tr['week']= tr.groupby('year').cumcount()+1
    tr2 = tr.pivot_table(index='week',columns='year')
    tr2['max07_13']=tr2.max(axis=1)   
    tr2['min07_13']=tr2.min(axis=1)

    print(tr2)
```

Which gives me this:

```
      Total Rigs                                            max07_13  min07_13
year        2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014                    
week                                                                          
1            408   333   303   322   419   382   270   477       477       270
2            539   449   357   382   495   541   460   514       541       357
3            581   482   355   419   511   554   502   509       581       355
4            597   485   356   441   514   568   502   502       597       356
5            587   496   340   462   522   570   503   500       587       340
6            590   521   304   457   526   564   506   512       590       304
7            586   539   294   465   517   571   519   530       586       294
8            555   529   282   455   517   555   517   NaN       555       282
9            550   534   232   437   532   519   518   NaN       550       232
10           510   502   160   366   528   419   472   NaN       528       160
11           396   411   107   259   466   296   405   NaN       466       107
```

...But I would like the two max/min columns on the right to only take the max/min for 2007-2013.  I have tried several indexing methods but seems to result in errors.

Any suggestions??

EDIT:

Tried the scalable solution but got the following error:

```
KeyError: "['2007' '2008' '2009' '2010' '2011' '2012' '2013'] not in index"
```

EDIT2:

tr2.columns output is the following:

```
            Year
Total Rigs  2007
            2008
            2009
            2010
            2011
            2012
            2013
            2014
 max07_13        
 min07_13
```

EDIT3:

This was the solution:

```
    gcols=[('Total Rigs',2007),('Total Rigs',2008),('Total Rigs',2009),('Total Rigs',2010),('Total Rigs',2011),('Total Rigs',2012),('Total Rigs',2013)]
    tr2['Max 2007-2013']=tr2[gcols].max(axis=1)   
    tr2['Min 2007-2013']=tr2[gcols].min(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a non-scalable solution would be to `drop` 2014 and then call `max` and `min` -

```
tr2['max07_13']=tr2.drop('2014', axis=1).max(axis=1)
```

If you know the columns of interest, you can also use that -

```
columns_of_interest = ['2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013']
tr2['max07_13']=tr2[columns_of_interest].max(axis=1)
```

Comment: See edit above. Also, thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @carevans88 , the columns might not be strings. Can you try - `columns_of_interest = [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]`

Comment: It also appears that you might have multilevel columns. If so, can you post the output of `tr2.columns`?

Comment: It appears to be multilevel, so you can use `columns_of_interest = [('Total Rigs', 2007), ('Total Rigs', 2008), ('Total Rigs', 2009), ('Total Rigs', 2010), ('Total Rigs', 2011), ('Total Rigs', 2012), ('Total Rigs', 2013)]`.